# How to perform leftJoin on tables from different databases(data sources) using Scala Slick?

Tags: scala, slick, playframework-2.5, slick-3.0

I have 2 databases (database1 and database2).

- database1 has table1 with field id
- database2 has table2 with field id

Now how do i perform leftJoin(as shown below) using Slick?

```
 SELECT tb1.`id`
 FROM `database1`.`table1` t1
 LEFT JOIN `database1`.`table2` t2 ON t1.`id`=t2.`id`
```

Answer (score 5):

I may be wrong here but most existing relational databases don't allow you to span multiple databases within single operation. However, what you showed above is easily achievable by using `schema` (and I strongly believe this is what you want to really achieve -judging by the SQL you pasted).

Let's have an example. Let's assume we have two tables defined within our `Slick`-related code as follows:

```
  // student
  case class Student(name: String,
                     middleName: Option[String],
                     surname: String,
                     nationality: String,
                     id: Id[Student] = Id.none)

  class StudentTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[Student](tag, "STUDENT") {
    def name = column[String]("NAME")
    def middleName = column[Option[String]]("MIDDLE_NAME")
    def surname = column[String]("SURNAME")
    def nationality = column[String]("NATIONALITY")
    def id = column[Id[Student]]("ID", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)

    def * = (name, middleName, surname, nationality, id) <> (Student.tupled, Student.unapply)
  }

  lazy val StudentTable = TableQuery[StudentTable]

  // document
  case class Document(studentId: Option[Id[Student]],
                      name: String,
                      uuid: String,
                      id: Id[Document] = Id.none)

  class DocumentTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[Document](tag, "DOCUMENT") {
    def studentId = column[Option[Id[Student]]]("STUDENT_ID")
    def name = column[String]("NAME")
    def uuid = column[String]("UUID")
    def id = column[Id[Document]]("ID", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)

    def * = (studentId, name, uuid, id) <> (Document.tupled, Document.unapply)

    def student = foreignKey("fk_document_student", studentId, StudentTable)(_.id.?)
  }

  lazy val DocumentTable = TableQuery[DocumentTable]
```

Doing following query:

```
    DocumentTable
      .joinLeft(StudentTable).on(_.studentId === _.id)
      .filter { case(doc, student) => student.map(_.name) === "Test" }
```

will generate following SQL:

```
select x2."STUDENT_ID", x2."NAME", x2."UUID", x2."ID", x3."NAME", x3."MIDDLE_NAME", x3."SURNAME", x3."NATIONALITY", x3."ID" 
from "DOCUMENT" x2 
left outer join "STUDENT" x3 on x2."STUDENT_ID" = x3."ID" 
where x3."NAME" = 'Test'
```

If I however change my table definition to:

```
class StudentTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[Student](tag, _schemaName = Option("database2"), "STUDENT") {
...
```

and this

```
class DocumentTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[Document](tag, _schemaName = Option("database1"), "DOCUMENT") {
...
```

**Notice that I added one parameter - `_schemaName` - which indicates that particular table should be prefixed by specified schema.**

I will have (same Slick query) following SQL generated now:

```
select x2."STUDENT_ID", x2."NAME", x2."UUID", x2."ID", x3."NAME", x3."MIDDLE_NAME", x3."SURNAME", x3."NATIONALITY", x3."ID" 
from "database1"."DOCUMENT" x2 
left outer join "database2"."STUDENT" x3 on x2."STUDENT_ID" = x3."ID" 
where x3."NAME" = 'Test'
```

which seems to be *precisely* what you want to achieve.