# Use multiple DB / Schema in a single DBIO in Slick

Tags: mysql, scala, slick, play-slick

Let's say If I have 2 Schema below.Both of them are in a same MySQL server.

- master
- base

The problem is I can't use more than 2 schema actions in a single Database `run`.
If I execute such plain sql queries via `sql`, It works without any problem.

```
def fooAction(name: String) = {
  sql"""
  SELECT AGE FROM MASTER.FOO_TABLE WHERE NAME = $name
  """.as[String].head
}

def barAction(id: String) = {
  sql"""
  SELECT BAZ FROM BASE.BAR_TABLE WHERE ID = $id
  """.as[String].head
}

def execute = {
  //It doesn't matter which Db I use in here But Let's say this baseDb is pointing to BASE schema.
  baseDb.run(for{
    foo <- fooAction("sample")
    bar <- barAction("sample")
  } yield foo + bar)
}
```

But the case of code blow doesn't

```
class FooTableDAO @Inject() (@NamedDatabase("master") protected val dbConfigProvider: DatabaseConfigProvider) extends HasDatabaseConfigProvider[JdbcProfile] {
  import dbConfig.driver.api._
  val table = TableQuery[FooTable]
  def fooAction(name: String) = table.filter{_.name == name}.map{_.age}.result.head
}
class BarTableDAO @Inject() (@NamedDatabase("base") protected val dbConfigProvider: DatabaseConfigProvider) extends HasDatabaseConfigProvider[JdbcProfile] {
  import dbConfig.driver.api._
  val table = TableQuery[BarTable]
  def fooAction(id: String) = table.filter{_.id == id}.map{_.baz}.result.head
}

def execute = {
  //com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'BASE.FOO_TABLE' doesn't exist
  baseDb.run(for{
    foo <- fooTableDAO.fooAction("sample")
    bar <- barTableDAO.barAction("sample")
  } yield foo + bar)
}
```

Since `baseDb` is pointing to BASE schema, It tries to find `FOO_TABLE` in MASTER schema. All What I want slick to do is use different schema for each query but I couldn't find the way.

Currently I do `DBIO.from(db.run(**))` if another schema action is needed in a for-comprehension of DBIO action or execute each actions via `run` and wrap them with `EitherT` which is scala library named `cats`'s monad transformer for `Either` to keep using for-comprehension.

Is there any way to handle more than 2 schemas in a single DBIO Action except using plain text query?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Would you also provide the slick version

Comment: @user2829759 it's play-slick 2.0 which is using slick 3.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think (though I am not an MySQL expert) you mean `schema`, not a `database`. At least this is what I see from your `SQL` samples.

Can't you just use *schema* attribute in your `Slick` table mappings? Here you have complete answer for using different schemas: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41090987/2239369

Here is the relevant piece of code:

```
class StudentTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[Student](tag, _schemaName = Option("database2"), "STUDENT") {
    ...
}
```

(notice `_schemaName` attribute).

With this in mind answer to this part of the question:

> Is there any way to handle more than 2 schemas in a single DBIO Action except using plain text query?

is: Yes you can.

Comment: Thanks for the info. This is exactly what I wanted to know.
FYI, database and schema are the same meaning in MySQL.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11618277/difference-between-schema-database-in-mysql